# Using :not() in CSS giving opposite desired result

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to highlight the current page list item in a menu having class of 'current_page_item'.

(In this example "About Us" list item.)

I'm having trouble excluding the 'children' class (sub ul) using :not() in CSS to exclude the children "Careers" from highlighting as well.

```
<div class="footer-widget-area">
  <ul>
    <li class="page_item page_item_has_children current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/newtheme/about-us/">About Us</a>
      <ul class='children'>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="http://localhost/newtheme/about-us/careers/">Careers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://localhost/newtheme/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://localhost/newtheme/press/">Press</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-widget-area .current_page_item :not(.children) a {background-color:yellow}
```

Using :not(.children) actually does the opposite of what I'm trying to do, by highlighting "Careers" (which is in .children ul class) and not "About Us" (which I want to highlight).

I've created a JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5vr0sqm5/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like you can just use the child selector for this: `.footer-widget-area .current_page_item > a {background-color:yellow}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to highlight the **direct children** of `.current-page-item` which is done with:

```
.footer-widget-area .current_page_item > a {background-color:yellow}
```

Comment: Simplest method by far...no need to complicate things here.

Answer (score 0):

To make `:not` work, I think what you want is:

```
.footer-widget-area .current_page_item > :not(.children) a {background-color:yellow}
```

or

```
.footer-widget-area .current_page_item ul:not(.children) a {background-color:yellow}
```

Otherwise the parent `li` will satisfy the query since it doesn't have the excluded class.